# Git cannot connect with SSH

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I noticed weird behavior in Git which appears randomly for time to time, so I successfully configured my SSH keys to connect with Bitbucket repository without any login or password, so I could pull my repository I made changes and when I want to commit it again shows me this

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident name (for <Username@Your-PC.(none)>) not allowed
```

This is so weird if something is wrong with SSH keys then how I can pull my repository, and also everything works fine apart from commiting

Comment: This has nothing to do with SSH.  You're just logged in as a different user, or you've deleted you global git configuration, or something like that. Configure your name and email as it requests.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not going to login with my username and email address, that is the advantage of using SSH to avoid entering your explicit credentials.

Comment: Git config is totally separate to SSH auth, it's just the identity Git will use to attach to your commits.

Comment: I have a git config file with my repository files .git/config

Comment: What is the result if you type the command `git config user.email` `git config user.name` when that message comes up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not use any user name password combination of any kind.
What it does require is to set user name and email since this information is part of a commit blob.

[image]

The user name and email are the minimum and the only information git requires you to set.

When using central repositories the administrator of such a repository can decide on which [***`Transfer protocols`***](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) he support and if the server support ***`ssh`*** yo will need to use ssh keys, for ***`https`*** you will need to use user/password combination to authenticate yourself .

In your case you simply need to set username & email to be used with the git commit.

---

Back to your original comment:

> This is so weird if something is wrong with SSH keys then how I can pull my repository, and also everything works fine apart from commiting

I hope now you understand why do you need this information.
You can see in the image above what does commit requires.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens because the email does not have the correct format :

wrong ==>> Username@Your-PC.(none)>) it does not have the  .com or .net

if you are using a server like Linux, make sure the hostname have a domain format like mydomain.com or myhostname.net